# How to transform hyperspectral 3d array to a 2d matrix in R

Tags: r

I have an array having dimension
128 128 1000
I would like to transform it to a 2d matrix in R
Any suggestions?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7nN7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done by changing `dim` of the `array`:

```
A <- array(1:(2*3*4), c(2,3,4))
dim(A) <- c(dim(A)[1], prod(dim(A)[2:3]))

 A
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
#[1,]    1    3    5    7    9   11   13   15   17    19    21    23
#[2,]    2    4    6    8   10   12   14   16   18    20    22    24
```

or

```
A <- array(1:(2*3*4), c(2,3,4))
dim(A) <- c(prod(dim(A)[1:2]), dim(A)[3])

A
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    7   13   19
#[2,]    2    8   14   20
#[3,]    3    9   15   21
#[4,]    4   10   16   22
#[5,]    5   11   17   23
#[6,]    6   12   18   24
```

In case other orders are needed `aperm` could be used.